# Communicate between usercontrols on form

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls

i want to call usercontrol function/method from another one by button click when my user control parent is form...

in form; i load and add user controls:

```
//Controls enum holding names of all our user controls
public enum ControlsEnum
{
    SPLASH_CONTROL,
    MAIN_CONTROL,
    CATEGORY_CONTROL,
}
public partial class MainForm : Form
{
    //Dictionary that holds all our instantiated user controls.
    private IDictionary<ControlsEnum, Control> controls = new Dictionary<ControlsEnum, Control>();

    public MainForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        //When the program runs for the first time, lets call the ShowControl method that
        //will show the first control
        ShowControl(ControlsEnum.SPLASH_CONTROL);
    }

    public void ShowControl(ControlsEnum ctrl)
    {
        Control new_ctrl = null;

        //If our dictionary already contains instance of
        if (controls.ContainsKey(ctrl))
        {
            new_ctrl = controls[ctrl];
        }
        else
        {
            new_ctrl = CreateControl(ctrl);
            controls[ctrl] = new_ctrl;
        }

        new_ctrl.Parent = this;
        new_ctrl.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        new_ctrl.BringToFront();
        new_ctrl.Show();
    }

    private Control CreateControl(ControlsEnum ctrl)
    {
        switch (ctrl)
        {
            case ControlsEnum.SPLASH_CONTROL:
                return new Splash_uc();
            case ControlsEnum.MAIN_CONTROL:
                return new Main_uc();
            case ControlsEnum.CATEGORY_CONTROL:
                return new Categoty_uc();
            default:
                return null;
        }
    }
```

and in Category_uc:

```
private void btn_categorySave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   // i want refresh datagridview and add new category to list by save in database
}
```

and in main_uc:

```
private void datagridview_Refresh()
{
  //rebind datagridview datasource
  // i want call this function from "category_uc" when click on Save Button
}
```

please help me! tnx;

Answer (score 1):

You can add an event to your control:

```
class Categoty_uc
{
  public event EventHandler ButtonClicked;

  protected OnButtonClicked()
  {
    var tmp = ButtonClicked;

    if(tmp != null)
    {
      tmp(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }
  }

  private void btn_categorySave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    OnButtonClicked();
  }
}
```

And then in your main form:

```
private Main_uc main_uc = null;

private Control CreateControl(ControlsEnum ctrl)
{
  Control ret = null;

  switch (ctrl)
  {
    case ControlsEnum.CATEGORY_CONTROL:
    {
      if(main_uc != null)
      {
        ret = new Categoty_uc();
        ((Categoty_uc)ret).ButtonClicked += (sender, e) => 
                          {main_uc.datagridview_Refresh();}
      }
      else
      {
        throw new Exception("Create Main_uc first!");
      }
    }
    break;
    case ControlsEnum.MAIN_CONTROL:
    {
      if(main_uc == null)
      {
        main_uc = new Main_uc();
      }
      ret = main_uc;
    }
  }

  return ret;
}
```

Comment: thanks for ur answer. i run ur code and have error: datagridview_Refresh doesnt exist.. . i want call datagridview_Refresh from category_uc(). and this function exist on main_uc...

Comment: If you want to do so, pass your Category_uc object to Main_uc object.
But why don't you want to call the function from MainForm as i suggested above?

Comment: What you need to do is to create public method at main_uc like `public void RefreshDataGridView()` and call it instead of `datagridview_Refresh()` from the MainForm.

Comment: I run your code, but the `public void RefreshDataGridView()` in `Main_uc` is not available on `Category_uc` and VS2012 will show an error: `The name RefreshDataGridView does not exist in the current context`. pls help! tnx.

Comment: Change `private void datagridview_Refresh()` to `public void datagridview_Refresh()` in your code. And see how i modified my answer.